# Getting time on Google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, date, time, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

So I'm writing a script which requires reading a time value from a Google spreadsheet and using it. I've tried to run a test function to ensure that the values being extracted are correct but it seems that the values are different from what is reflected on the spreadsheet.

Input

```
function testTime(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("TimeSheet");
  var time = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue();
  //value on the sheet is 10:00:00 AM 
  Logger.log(time);
  Logger.log(time.toTimeString());
}
```

Output

```
Sat Dec 30 09:30:59 GMT+07:36 1899
09:54:17 GMT+0800 (HKT)
```

The time is supposed to be 10:00:00 but is reflected as 09:54:17 instead which is the first weird error.

Secondly is there anyway where I can extract the actual value "10:00:00 AM" or even better in a the simpler format "10:00"?

**EDIT:**

I've found a way to solve the second issue and get the time in the desired format. However, there is still some weird interaction with the time. I've added 2 lines and it's respective output

All the logger lines

```
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+07:37", "HH:mm"));
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+08:00", "HH:mm"));
  Logger.log(time);
  Logger.log(time.toTimeString());
```

Output

```
10:00
10:23
Sat Dec 30 10:00:00 GMT+07:36 1899
10:23:18 GMT+0800 (HKT)
```

Under spreadsheet settings,

Locale = United States

Time Zone = (GMT+08:00) Hong Kong

Comment: This looks like a time zone issue, how did you get a timezone that's GMT+7:36?! Can you look up the time zone settings in File > Spreadsheet Settings as well as the full value of the time as a number?

Comment: So I've found a way to get the desired time format. Now the real issue is with the correctness of the time. According to the spreadsheet settings, Locale is United States, Time Zone is (GMT+08:00) Hong Kong. I've revised the logging and it has given me the following output.

(NEW)First Log with correct format: 10:23
Second Log same as above: Sat Dec 30 10:00:00 GMT+07:36 1899
Third Log same as above: 10:23:18 GMT+0800 (HKT)

Comment: Very interesting, in the script editor if you go to File > Project properties what's the time zone there? DO you have any user properties or script properties set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to have exactly the same value as shown in spreadsheet
   cell, use  `var time = sheet.getRange(2,1).getDisplayValue();`
2. Also, you can break apart the long date/time string by using 
   `split(" ")` method and then combining elements from resulting array in whatever way you want.

Comment: Oh my goodness, that getDisplayValue() method worked wonders. Thanks so much. I totally didn't need to play around with time zones.

Answer (score 0):

Upon experimenting with Utilities.formatDate and Time Zone settings on both the spreadsheet and script files, I've found a solution for both issues.

1. Issue with Time

Even though I'm in Singapore, I've set the Time Zone to (GMT+8:00) Taipei and it gives me the correct time which is 10:00:00AM. Don't know why but I guess it works

2. Issue with Format

I simply used

```
Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+08:00", "HH:mm"));
```

which gave me my desired format which is

```
10:00
```